# I'm making a flask quiz web page and I'm trying to print the score to the user

Tags: python, flask

I am making a quiz with flask and I am trying to get the score for the user but every time I reload the page I get this error: 'TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.'

The quiz includes questions that is stored on a database using sqlalchemy. I have successfully queried the database to display the questions on my page

This is the code for the html which display the questions on the page

```
<h5 class="center-align">Answer the Questions</h5>
        <form action="http://localhost:5000/info" method='POST'>
                {% for computersystemsq in computersystemsq %}
                {% for computersystemsm in computersystemsm %}

                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12">
                                {{ computersystemsq.question }}
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="{{ computersystemsm.id }}"></div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col s6">
                                    A: {{ computersystemsm.wrong_answer1 }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col s6">
                                    B: {{ computersystemsm.wrong_answer2 }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col s6">
                                    C: {{ computersystemsm.answer }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                        <div class="input-field col s6">
                                            {{ form.options( class= computersystemsm.id ) }}
                                            <label for="attempted_answer">Select an Option:</label>                 
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" id="{{ computersystemsm.id }}">mark</button>
            <br>
                    </div>  
                {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}





        </form>
```

This is the query made to get the computersystemsquestions and the computersystemsmultiplechoices from the table(two tables, computersystemsquestions stores the question and computersystemsmultiplechoices stores the answer, wrong_answer1, wrong_answer2)

```
@app.route("/computersystems", methods=['GET','POST'])
def computersystems():
    form=QuizForm()
    computersystemsq=ComputerSystemsQuestions.query.filter(ComputerSystemsQuestions.id).all()
    computersystemsm=ComputerSystemsMultipleChoices.query.filter(ComputerSystemsMultipleChoices.id).all()
    return render_template('computersystems.html',computersystemsq=computersystemsq,computersystemsm=computersystemsm, form=form)
```

this is the code which I'm using to store the request values and to get the score

```
@app.route("/info", methods=['GET','POST'])
def info():

    value = request.args.get('value', 0, type=str)
    computersystemsm=ComputerSystemsMultipleChoices.query.filter(ComputerSystemsMultipleChoices.id).all()
    #if request.method == 'POST':
    quizscore = 0
    if computersystemsm[0].answer == value:
        quizscore = quizscore + 1
        return render_template('info.html', quizscore=quizscore,computersystemsm=computersystemsm)
```

I am expecting to get a score displayed to the user doing the question like so:

```
<p>you've scored {{quizscore }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Flask you will need to account for all possible outcomes when designing a `view` (route). In your last code snippet, there are a few things to mention. Firstly, create some logic to handle the different methods that your view is supporting.

```
def info():
    if (request.method == 'GET'):
        pass
    elif (request.method == 'POST'):
        pass
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#http-methods

You could use `else` statement instead of the `elif` but I prefer this way so that I can easily add support for a `PUT` method if necessary in the future.

Secondly, you need to return something for when your `if` statement equates to `False`.

I would suggest:

```
if computersystemsm[0].answer == value:
    quizscore = quizscore + 1
    return render_template('info.html', quizscore=quizscore,computersystemsm=computersystemsm)
else:
    return abort(500)
```

This will return a generic internal server error if your logic does not equate to `True`. If you use this method, make sure you have imported `abort`

```
from flask import abort
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors

Comment: i did this:
def info():
    value = request.args.get('value', 0, type=str)
    computersystemsm=ComputerSystemsMultipleChoices.query.filter(ComputerSystemsMultipleChoices.id).all()
    if (request.method == 'GET'):
        pass
    elif (request.method == 'POST'):
        quizscore = 0
        if computersystemsm[0].answer == value:
            quizscore = quizscore + 1
            return render_template('info.html', quizscore=quizscore,computersystemsm=computersystemsm)
        else:
            return abort(500)   now I'm getting an internal server error

Comment: Good. Now you can debug why ```value``` does not equal ```computersystemsm[0].answer```. Now it is a logic error and not syntax error :) If you replace (JUST FOR TESTING) ```if if computersystemsm[0].answer == value:``` with ```if True```, the page will render but without correct error handling. You should be able to work from here, if there is another issue, please feel free to add another comment :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm still kinda stuck on figuring out why I'm not getting the score displayed so I'm thinking maybe if I can actually see the data that is being sent to me from the post request, it would help with figuring out what the problem is. Can you help me with how I can view the answer that is being given when submit button is clicked?

Comment: You are handling the request arguments with this line: ```value = request.args.get('value', 0, type=str)```. Try printing ```value``` and ```computersystemsm[0].answer``` together and manually compare results.